# Series Solutions for Differential Equation (similar to Airy function)

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, airy-functions

I have to find a series solution to:

$$y'' - t^3 y =0$$

I go through the steps like so,

$$\sum_2 n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2} - \sum_0 a_n x^{n+3} = $$
$$\sum_0 (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2} x^{k} - \sum_3 a_{k-3} x^{k} =$$

I am struggling to get the indices to math and I'm not sure of any methods to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Writing $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)a_n x^{n-2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n+3}=0$$ (I suggest you do not change the indices). Now, consider the above for  power $n-2$ ; so $$n(n-1)a_{n}-a_{n-5}=0$$ (as you wrote). So,  $$a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-5}}{n(n-1)}$$ with $a_2=a_3=a_4=0$. Since you face a second order differential equation, coefficients $a_0$ and $a_1$ are free (until you have conditions).

Comment: Just a quick question, why doesn't the index change on the right summation when you try to switch it to match $n-2$, I assume the substituion is like $k - 2 = n +3, \therefore n = k -5$

Comment: If you want $x^{n-2}$  on the right summation you need $a_{n-5}$, isn't it ? The all stuff is just to consider the same power of $x$ in both summations. Say : power $k$; so for the left $(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}$ and for the right $a_{k-3}$. Now, shift the indices. Is this clear for you ? If not, just post.

Comment: it's more like, i'm confused. Can you just jump from $a_{n}$ to $a_{n-5}$ without the index changing to $n=-5$?